# iOS 6 Apple LLVM 4.1 Error

Tags: osx-lion, clang, xcode4.5

I tring build project to for iPad to xCode. And I've received the following mistake

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

How to solve this priblem? All report:

```
/Users/sreenivas//Decoder/mc-a.S:305:15: error: unknown token in expression
    .align
          ^
/Users/sreenivas//Decoder/mc-a.S:317:18: error: invalid operand for instruction
    ldrd r4, [sp, #20]
             ^
```

i am using Mac OS 10.7.5 & Xcode 4.5.

this is working fine on Mac OS 10.7.5 & Xcode 4.2.3.

what is the problem any one please help? can i add any flag's for Xcode 4.5:

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.5 uses a new, stricter parser for assembly by default.  Specifically, it's expecting you to provide a number to `.align`, and two registers for ldrd.

As a temporary workaround, you can switch back to the old assembler by adding the flag `-no-integrated-as` to your compiler flags.